# How to replace an entire line in text file by only knowing a portion of the line?

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that contains a like that is similar to

`Settings amount ="01:00:00"`

I know how to replace the line but my issue is at the moment I am only able to replace the entire line if I know the exact contents of the line- using `-match` and `-replace`. However, is there a way that I can search for just `Settings amount =` and then just replace that entire line with my new setting? That way no matter what the current value is I have the power to scan and give it a different value.

This is what I have currently.

```
$DesiredTime = 'Settings amount="06:00:00" />'

$path = "C:\Windows\File.txt" 
 (Get-Content $path) -replace 'Settings amount="01:00:00" />', $DesiredTime | out-file $path
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look at [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1). It will allow you to find the entire line that contains what you are looking for. Then you can update the line.

This is a sample file

```
apple = yummy
bananna = yummy
pear = awful
grapes = divine
```

Say I want to replace the line containing "pear". First get the line:

```
$line = Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt | Select-String pear | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
```

Now we just read in the content and replace the line with our line:

```
$content = Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt
$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line,"pear = amazing"} | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

Confirm the changes

```
Get-Content C:\temp\test.txt
apple = yummy
bananna = yummy
pear = amazing
grapes = divine
```

Note that if you are working with XML, which it looks like you might be you can open the document as an XML document and simply replace the attribute. Without seeing a sample of your source file its hard to tell.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this I didn't know know that existed. Could you maybe help me out with an example? How could I use that to find my line by only knowing `Setting amount = ` but then replace the entire line with something else?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example for reading in from text, finding the line, replacing it, and saving

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for the code. Works well but just want to add that this goes bad if the string is not found at all.  It will replace every line in your file.  This fixed up my issue with that by checking for null:

```
$line = Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt | Select-String pear | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line

if ($line -eq $null) {
"String Not Found"
exit
} else {
$content = Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt
$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line,"pear = amazing"} | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt

}
```

Comment: This is a very good point which helped me out alot. If your not careful you can loose everything that way.