# How to replace an entire line in text file by only knowing a portion of the line (CONTAINING *)?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace lines of text with a part of the text not always being a static value.

I have found that the method described in the post below is working except in one case where the line variable I am trying to change is containing an asterisk (*).

[How to replace an entire line in text file by only knowing a portion of the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601554/how-to-replace-an-entire-line-in-text-file-by-only-knowing-a-portion-of-the-line/53085526#53085526)

Otherwise if in testing I remove the asterisk it works. How can I have it ignore that there is what it thinks is a wildcard in the variable and just treat the * as more text?

```
$line = Get-Content D:\tmp\test.txt | Select-String TextString | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
Get-Content D:\tmp\test.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line,'TextString = VALUEIWANT'} | Set-Content D:\tmp\TEXTNEW.txt
```

Comment: it sounds like the regex engine is choking on the reserved character `*`. if so, you can escape that character and it will be treated as a  literal asterisk. the easiest way to escape chars in a string [for me] is to use the builtin dotnet `[regex]::Escape($YourStringHere)` method to generate an escaped version of the string.

Comment: Awesome that worked. Thank You very much!!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]