# Replace line in file by only knowing part of line with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using a modified version of the code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601554/how-to-replace-an-entire-line-in-text-file-by-only-knowing-a-portion-of-the-line/47602758).

```
$fileToCheck = "c:\Users\me\desktop\test.txt"

$fileContents = Get-Content $fileToCheck

$line = $fileContents | Select-String "hosts" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line

if ($line -eq $null) {
    "String Not Found"
    exit
}

echo $line

$modifiedContents = $fileContents | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line,'hey'}

echo $modifiedContents
```

This is my `test.txt` file's contents:

```
X.Y:
  hosts: ["https://localhost:111"]
```

There are 2 whitespaces preceding `hosts`.

I am unable to get the line to be replaced. I've narrowed it down to the fact that it is probably due to one of the special characters that are being used in that line, which is causing the issue.

I've tried the modified code with the original data and everything works.

Not sure what gives in my case?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: If your aim is to replace the whole line `'  hosts: ["https://localhost:111"]'` with value `hey`, then you need to escape the special characters using `[regex]::Escape($line)`. Can you show us the desired output?

Comment: @Theo The desired output is actually `  hosts: ["https://a.b.c.d:111"]`. Thank you so much!

Comment: In short: PowerShell's [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) _operator_ is _regex_-based and case-_insensitive_ by default. To perform _literal_ replacement, `\ `-escape metacharacters in the pattern or call `[regex]::Escape()`.
By contrast, the `[string]` type's [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) _method_ performs _literal_ replacement and is case-_sensitive_, _invariably_ in Windows PowerShell, _by default_ in PowerShell (Core).
See the [answer to the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your script and changed `-replace` to `.Replace()` and it works fine:

```
$modifiedContents = $fileContents | ForEach-Object {$_.Replace($line,'hey')}
```

You're trying to do a literal replacement, but you're using `-replace`, which involves regexes and as Theo suggested in the comment you need to escape special characters if you want to stick to the `-replace`.